# How Does one animate a image zooming in without Hover/clicking

Tags: javascript, animation

I need to make the opening page were you see the logo for a channel on You tube zoom in on screen to the full screen size, but i dont know how to make it automatically zoom with hover/click. Pls help i dont know much on javascript but willing to learn

Comment: Your question is unclear. In the title you write _**without** Hover/clicking_ and in the question you write _automatically zoom **with** hover/click_ - do you mean zoom _with_ or zoom _without_ the actions listed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using JavaScript, you can put the zoom animation in the [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) event. It fires when the page finish loading.

```
window.onload = function(event){
    // Your animation code goes here
}
```